# Display the Business data that reside on PDW to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, list-view, content-database, external-content-type

I was trying to display the Business data that reside on PDW or APS (parallel data warehouse),  to SharePoint list .And to do so I tried to connect to the database server using SharePoint designer external Content Type feature but wasn't able to. I am not sure if SharePoint allows to connect to External Data source (PDW). I would appreciate if someone could assist me.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163975.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure that the Business Data Connection Services is Activated and the external content type you have created contains information about connections, access, methods of operation, columns etc. Please follow this article to get further help:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-update-an-external-data-column-in-a-list-or-library-44EFF2C5-8051-489D-989C-F5D09F527AEE